# How to split image into smaller rectangles for iPhone, Android, or Rails?

Tags: iphone, android, ruby-on-rails, image, image-processing

My client would like to create an iPhone & Android app that turns custom photos into jigsaw puzzles. (Yes, we know these exist already.) What's the best way to take a custom image and split it into smaller rectangles?

This SO post is close (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991302/algorithm-to-split-an-image-into-smaller-images-reducing-the-amount-of-whitespace), but we're wondering if there are any libraries to facilitate the process either for mobile devices or even for Rails (i.e., we perform the image processing on the server instead of on the client).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that ImageMagick, http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php, would be suitable for this task on the server side. IIRC, Rails has a gem that integrates with ImageMagick nicely.