# Is There Any Standard Algorithm In Digital Image Processing that Divides Input RGB image into Sub-Images of Desired Size (Example 8x8)

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing

Hello I am a beginner in digital image processing, i just want to know that is there any standard algorithm? that divides input RGB image into sub-images of desired size and then combines these sub-images to form the original image.

Answer (score 3):

```
% Demo to divide a color image up into blocks.
clc;    % Clear the command window.
close all;  % Close all figures (except those of imtool.)
workspace;  % Make sure the workspace panel is showing.
fontSize = 20;

% Read in a standard MATLAB color demo image.
folder = fullfile(matlabroot, '\toolbox\images\imdemos');
baseFileName = 'peppers.png';
% Get the full filename, with path prepended.
fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
if ~exist(fullFileName, 'file')
    % Didn't find it there.  Check the search path for it.
    fullFileName = baseFileName; % No path this time.
    if ~exist(fullFileName, 'file')
        % Still didn't find it.  Alert user.
        errorMessage = sprintf('Error: %s does not exist.', fullFileName);
        uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
        return;
    end
end
% Read the image from disk.
rgbImage = imread(fullFileName);

% Test code if you want to try it with a gray scale image.
% Uncomment line below if you want to see how it works with a gray scale image.
% rgbImage = rgb2gray(rgbImage);

% Display image full screen.
imshow(rgbImage);
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);
drawnow;
% Get the dimensions of the image.  numberOfColorBands should be = 3.
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(rgbImage)

%==========================================================================
% The first way to divide an image up into blocks is by using mat2cell().
blockSizeR = 150; % Rows in block.
blockSizeC = 100; % Columns in block.

% Figure out the size of each block in rows. 
% Most will be blockSizeR but there may be a remainder amount of less than that.
wholeBlockRows = floor(rows / blockSizeR);
blockVectorR = [blockSizeR * ones(1, wholeBlockRows), rem(rows, blockSizeR)];
% Figure out the size of each block in columns. 
wholeBlockCols = floor(columns / blockSizeC);
blockVectorC = [blockSizeC * ones(1, wholeBlockCols), rem(columns, blockSizeC)];

% Create the cell array, ca.  
% Each cell (except for the remainder cells at the end of the image)
% in the array contains a blockSizeR by blockSizeC by 3 color array.
% This line is where the image is actually divided up into blocks.
if numberOfColorBands > 1
    % It's a color image.
    ca = mat2cell(rgbImage, blockVectorR, blockVectorC, numberOfColorBands);
else
    ca = mat2cell(rgbImage, blockVectorR, blockVectorC);
end

% Now display all the blocks.
plotIndex = 1;
numPlotsR = size(ca, 1);
numPlotsC = size(ca, 2);
for r = 1 : numPlotsR
    for c = 1 : numPlotsC
        fprintf('plotindex = %d,   c=%d, r=%d\n', plotIndex, c, r);
        % Specify the location for display of the image.
        subplot(numPlotsR, numPlotsC, plotIndex);
        % Extract the numerical array out of the cell
        % just for tutorial purposes.
        rgbBlock = ca{r,c};
        imshow(rgbBlock); % Could call imshow(ca{r,c}) if you wanted to.
        [rowsB columnsB numberOfColorBandsB] = size(rgbBlock);
        % Make the caption the block number.
        caption = sprintf('Block #%d of %d\n%d rows by %d columns', ...
            plotIndex, numPlotsR*numPlotsC, rowsB, columnsB);
        title(caption);
        drawnow;
        % Increment the subplot to the next location.
        plotIndex = plotIndex + 1;
    end
end

% Display the original image in the upper left.
subplot(4, 6, 1);
imshow(rgbImage);
title('Original Image');

%==============================================================================
% Another way to split the image up into blocks is to use indexing.
% Read in a standard MATLAB gray scale demo image.
folder = fullfile(matlabroot, '\toolbox\images\imdemos');
baseFileName = 'cameraman.tif';
fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
% Get the full filename, with path prepended.
fullFileName = fullfile(folder, baseFileName);
if ~exist(fullFileName, 'file')
    % Didn't find it there.  Check the search path for it.
    fullFileName = baseFileName; % No path this time.
    if ~exist(fullFileName, 'file')
        % Still didn't find it.  Alert user.
        errorMessage = sprintf('Error: %s does not exist.', fullFileName);
        uiwait(warndlg(errorMessage));
        return;
    end
end
grayImage = imread(fullFileName);
% Get the dimensions of the image.  numberOfColorBands should be = 1.
[rows columns numberOfColorBands] = size(grayImage);
% Display the original gray scale image.
figure;
subplot(2, 2, 1);
imshow(grayImage, []);
title('Original Grayscale Image', 'FontSize', fontSize);
% Enlarge figure to full screen.
set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]);

% Divide the image up into 4 blocks.
% Let's assume we know the block size and that all blocks will be the same size.
blockSizeR = 128; % Rows in block.
blockSizeC = 128; % Columns in block.
% Figure out the size of each block. 
wholeBlockRows = floor(rows / blockSizeR);
wholeBlockCols = floor(columns / blockSizeC);
% Preallocate a 3D image
image3d = zeros(wholeBlockRows, wholeBlockCols, 3);
% Now scan though, getting each block and putting it as a slice of a 3D array.
sliceNumber = 1;
for row = 1 : blockSizeR : rows
    for col = 1 : blockSizeR : columns
        % Let's be a little explicit here in our variables
        % to make it easier to see what's going on.
        row1 = row;
        row2 = row1 + blockSizeR - 1;
        col1 = col;
        col2 = col1 + blockSizeC - 1;
        % Extract out the block into a single subimage.
        oneBlock = grayImage(row1:row2, col1:col2);
        % Specify the location for display of the image.
        subplot(2, 2, sliceNumber);
        imshow(oneBlock);
        % Make the caption the block number.
        caption = sprintf('Block #%d of 4', sliceNumber);
        title(caption);
        drawnow;
        % Assign this slice to the image we just extracted.
        image3D(:, :, sliceNumber) = oneBlock;
        sliceNumber = sliceNumber + 1;
    end
end
% Now image3D is a 3D image where each slice, 
% or plane, is one quadrant of the original 2D image.

msgbox('Done with demo!  Check out the two figures.');
```

Also you can look at this post [Algorithm to split an image into smaller images reducing the amount of whitespace and specifying maximum amount of rectangles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991302/algorithm-to-split-an-image-into-smaller-images-reducing-the-amount-of-whitespac)

Comment: You should try some googling, as for as i know Divide and conquer algorithm is suitable,look at this link http://martin.lipinsky.cz/skola/pc/ccl/fast_ccl.pdf

Answer (score 3):

MATLAB provides you with a function called `blockproc`. In your case, with an input image `I`, you would say `I2 = blockproc(I, [8, 8], @fun);` where `fun` is a function you define. http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html shows simple examples.

Note that this is really only for the case where you want to split an image `I` into tiles of a given size, like 8 by 8, process each tile in some particular way defined by `fun`, and then reassemble an image `I2` from the results of each tile.

The result can be a single number or a matrix, either works, but the use of `blockproc` is really limited to the case where you divide into tiles, process each tile, and then reassemble the results into an output image. At that, however, it is extremely convenient.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `reshape` to accomplish that. For example, say we have an RGB image of 64x64 pixels

```
im=rand(64,64,3);
```

Let's divide it to 8x8 matrices

```
ims=reshape(im,8,8,3,[]);
size(ims)
ans =
 8     8     3    64
```

and `im=reshape(ims,64,64,[]);` will get it back to the same size it had.

so that was a crude example of dividing the image to 64 sub-matrices each keeps its RGB components. Most likely that what you need, won't use this generic reshaping, but instead will need to apply some function on a local neighborhood. For example 2-d median fileting using `medfilt2(im,[8 8])` or local standard deviation of image `stdfilt(im, [8 8])`, or `blockproc` that was mentioned already, etc...
So when you'll get to the point you'll know what you want, please ask a more specific question...

Comment: I actually want an image to split into n sub blocks and then want to perform some calculations on these blocks separately and after that i want to merge these blocks to form the original image....

Comment: but that is exactly what I did,  the n-th block which is 8x8x3 (since it is RGB) is just `ims(:,:,:,n)` , and calculation you want to perform on an n-th block you perform on `ims(:,:,:,n)`.